# What does ってのか mean in this sentence?

Tags: expressions

In this sentence:

> 俺にあの日の再現をさせようってのか

I know that ってのか is short for というのか.

But what does he mean by that sentence?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, っての/ってん is short for というの. Here, it's followed by か, so it's basically "Are you saying ～?", "Is it that ～?" or "Does that mean ～?".

- [がってんなら - what kind of contraction am I dealing with in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74618/5010)
- [ってんだ with imperative](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17469/5010)

The remaining part is a rather simple causative + volitional sentence.

> あの日の再現をする
> to re-enact that day (literally "to do the re-enactment of that day")
>
> 俺にあの日の再現をさせる (causative)
> to make me re-enact that day
>
> 俺にあの日の再現をさせようってのか (volitional + ってのか)
> = 俺にあの日の再現をさせようというのか
> Does that mean you're trying to make me re-enact that day?

(This あの日の再現 may euphemistically mean "to repeat the same mistake I made on that day" or something similar, depending on what happened on the あの日.)