# How can I break down the grammar of 黙って待ってろってのか?

Tags: meaning, conjugations

I am reading a manga and came across the following sentence

> このまま俺ら妖魔のエサになるを黙って待ってろってのか

I can sort of make sense of what the meaning is. Something along the lines of "In this situation should we silently wait to become ghost food?"

The thing is I can't break down 黙って待ってろってのか completely. This is what I get so far:

> 黙って - silently
> の - turns the previous bit into a noun
> か - is the question marker

what is the grammar behind 待ってろって though?

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/80785/45489

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the linked question, this ～ってのか is a shortened ～というのか？

黙って here is 'shut up, and...' rather than 'silently' (though I guess you could interpret that as the same thing). I think you've missed a の after なる too.

待ってろ is 待っていろ, the imperative of 待っている 'be waiting'. While we generally don't use tenses this way in English, its difference from simply 待て is basically that it implies 'remain waiting'.

> You telling us to shut up and wait to be demon food?!